# angular 11 polyfill now working in ie11 , How do I working on IE11?

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular, typescript, ecmascript-6

I use Angular 11 + typescript 4.0

Chrome is fine but It is not working in IE11

**IE11 Does not show errors in console.**

How do I working on IE 11?

Before I changed es6 => es5 in polyfill
but still not working

and I added 'tsconfig-es5.app.json'

```
     _                      _                 ____ _     ___
    / \   _ __   __ _ _   _| | __ _ _ __     / ___| |   |_ _|
   / △ \ | '_ \ / _` | | | | |/ _` | '__|   | |   | |    | |
  / ___ \| | | | (_| | |_| | | (_| | |      | |___| |___ | |
 /_/   \_\_| |_|\__, |\__,_|_|\__,_|_|       \____|_____|___|
                |___/
    

Angular CLI: 11.0.4
Node: 12.16.2
OS: linux x64

Angular: 11.0.4
... animations, cli, common, compiler, compiler-cli, core, forms
... language-service, platform-browser, platform-browser-dynamic
... router
Ivy Workspace: Yes

Package                         Version
---------------------------------------------------------
@angular-devkit/architect       0.1100.4
@angular-devkit/build-angular   0.1100.4
@angular-devkit/core            11.0.4
@angular-devkit/schematics      11.0.4
@angular/cdk                    11.0.3
@angular/flex-layout            9.0.0-beta.31
@angular/material               11.0.3
@schematics/angular             11.0.4
@schematics/update              0.1100.4
rxjs                            6.6.3
typescript                      4.1.3
```

polyfill.ts

```
import 'core-js/es6/symbol';
import 'core-js/es6/object';
import 'core-js/es6/function';
import 'core-js/es6/parse-int';
import 'core-js/es6/parse-float';
import 'core-js/es6/number';
import 'core-js/es6/math';
import 'core-js/es6/string';
import 'core-js/es6/date';
import 'core-js/es6/regexp';
import 'core-js/es6/map';
import 'core-js/es6/weak-map';
import 'core-js/es6/set';
import 'core-js/es6/array';
import 'core-js/es7/array';
import 'core-js/modules/es.array.includes';

import 'classlist.js';  


import 'core-js/es6/reflect';
import 'core-js/es7/reflect';

import 'web-animations-js'; 

(window as any).__Zone_enable_cross_context_check = true; 
import 'zone.js/dist/zone.js'
```

```
{
  "compileOnSave": false,
  "compilerOptions": {
    "paths": {
      "core-js/es7/reflect": [
        "node_modules/core-js/proposals/reflect-metadata",
      ],
      "core-js/es6/*": ["node_modules/core-js/es"]
    },
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "baseUrl": "./",
    "outDir": "./dist/out-tsc",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "declaration": false,
    "downlevelIteration": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "module": "es2020",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "importHelpers": true,
    "target": "es5",
    "lib": [
      "es2018",
      "dom",
      "es5", "es6", "dom.iterable"
    ]
  },
  "angularCompilerOptions": {
    "fullTemplateTypeCheck": true,
    "strictInjectionParameters": true
  }
}
```

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=11">
```

it does not recognize polyfill . is there anything to add to index.html?

Comment: is polyfill loaded BEFORE your bundle ?

Comment: yes ........................................

Comment: @NnieVi did you manage to get it working? I have the same problem here